# override product/price/msrp.phtml template

Tags: overrides, magento-2.0.6

In my module I created \view\frontend\layout\catalog_product_prices.xml

```
<layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
    <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="msrp_price" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                        <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">MyVendor_MyModule::product/price/msrp.phtml</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
</layout>
```

but my custom product/price/msrp.phtml template did not override core template. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the name of your module is ***Yourvendor_Yourmodule***.

1. Create `app/code/Yourvendor/Yourmodule` directory
2. Create file `app/code/Yourvendor/Yourmodule/registration.php`:

   ```
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
       'Yourvendor_Yourmodule',
       __DIR__
   );
   ```
3. Create file `app/code/Yourvendor/Yourmodule/etc/module.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Yourvendor_Yourmodule" setup_version="1.0.0">
       <sequence>
           <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
           <module name="Magento_Msrp"/>
       </sequence>
   </module>
   </config>
   ```
4. Create file `app/code/Yourvendor/Yourmodule/view/base/layout/catalog_product_prices.xml`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <layout xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/layout_generic.xsd">
       <referenceBlock name="render.product.prices">
           <arguments>
               <argument name="default" xsi:type="array">
               <item name="prices" xsi:type="array">
                   <item name="msrp_price" xsi:type="array">
                       <item name="render_class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\PriceBox</item>
                       <item name="render_template" xsi:type="string">Yourvendor_Yourmodule::product/price/msrp.phtml</item>
                   </item>
               </item>
               </argument>
           </arguments>
       </referenceBlock>
   </layout>
   ```
5. Create file `app/code/Yourvendor/Yourmodule/view/base/templates/product/price/msrp.phtml` and put some content in order to be sure that it's used on frontend.

Perform following commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Depending on your environment setup and mode, you'll have to execute

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Go to the page with msrp set, and check if it works.

### If it still doesn't work

Check `\Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\RendererPool`. If you have installed debug, you can observer `findDataByPattern()` function in order to see what renderer is getting assigned. If you don't have xdebug, then just put `$renderers = $this->getData(); var_dump($renderers['default']['prices']); die();` somewhere in `findDataPattern()` and check what templates are used for rendering different type of prices.